# Running h5dump from C

Tags: c, dump, hdf

I have a file in .h5 format: file.h5. I want to write a program that get a binary file output from file.h5. In ruby it is easy to run an external program h5dump with -b, -d, -o parameters on my file. I need to do the same in C. Is it possible to do the same but in C?

To clarify, from terminal I can run it by: h5dump -d /dataset -b -o out.dat file.h5
In ruby, I just define the names, write class to run the h5dump with arguments and it is all. What about the same in C?

Comment: Do you want to execute the terminal command from C code or do you want to implement what h5dump utility do?

Comment: I think right now about both options. Running the terminal command from C would be the best option, because I am afraid that implementation of h5dump in C will be difficult for me.

Comment: What about `system` from C standard library?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read about system() and the execution was so simple! My mistake was that I focused on finding "executing h5dump in C". Instead I should find the running terminal command.